# Delete one whitespace to the left

Tags: vim

Consider this code:

```
foo = (int)someVariable - 42;
bar = someFunction('someArgument') + 42;
```

By placing the cursor on the leading character of `someVariable` and `someFunction` we can experiment with `dw`, `daw`, and `diw`. We can see that the commands have the following behaviour regarding the deletion of whitespace from the Left and Right sides:

```
      L?   R?
    ----------
daw   Y    Y
 dw   .    Y
diw   .    .

L?: Deletes whitespace from the left
R?: Deletes whitespace from the right
```

The `daw` command will delete whitespace from either side of the text, whereas `dw` will only delete from the right and `diw` will not delete whitespace from either side. Is there a command that will delete whitespace only from the **left**, but not from the **right**?

Note that this is not an issue that I am having with VIM, but rather my experimentation to learn the editor better.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a command. In most languages, a space is used *after* a word to separate it from the following. This is the rule more or less followed by Vim. That said, it appears to work differently in code than in prose: `daw` with the cursor anywhere on `someFunction` will also delete the space between it and `=`. If you remove this space, your code still means something while you'd get gibberish if you'd removed the space between `lorem ipsum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but you can improvise: `bXde`